# Are parts parameter supposed to agree with each other in datasheets

Tags: components, power-dissipation, device-characteristics

Say, given a power BJT that has a \$V_{CE_{SAT}}\$ = 2V and rated at \$I_{C_{MAX}}\$ = 6A, but \$P_{MAX}\$ = 8W.

Clearly, even only considering the \$P_{C}\$, it cannot continuously provide that current near saturation (assuming we put a collector resistor, worse even if we don't).

Then again, most of the times a heatsink tab is provided in the package, extending the power dissipation; maybe that's a way for them to justify the 6A.

Or maybe this justification isn't industry practice? Is it alright if certain parameters don't agree?

Comment: You should read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_operating_area  Indeed you are not allowed to violate **any** of the limits, So when Pmax = 8W and at Vce_sat = 2 V you cannot make Ic larger than 4 A otherwise you would violate Pmax. So yes, it is OK that the parameters do not agree as they are not supposed to have that value **at the same time**. How you use the transistor will determine what the limiting parameter will be. If you make Vce lower, say 0.2 V then Ic can be 6 A and not violate Pmax.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, what you see is common.  Each spec is a limit on its own.  Under some conditions somehow, you can get the maximum collector current thru the thing.  That doesn't mean it can sustain that, especially when other maximums are reached.

About all the max C-E current spec tells you is the maximum short term pulse current.

Transistor datasheets are notorious for citing a high current in the marketing blurb at the top of the page, but after reading other specs you realize there is no way that current can ever be sustained due to the maximum dissipation spec.

Unfortunately, that's the current state of datasheets.  The best practice is to totally ignore the bullet points in the front.  Only the real min/max specs matter.

Answer (score 1):

Ic (max) doesn't usually mean continuous current whereas Power max usually does mean continuous average power. So if your Vce (sat) is 2 volts and the power is 8 watts, the average current cannot be above 4 amps but it could be on for 6 amps for some part of the duty cycle and off for the other part of the duty cycle. Read the data sheet again and digest the small print.

Answer (score -1):

> Are parts parameter supposed to agree with each other in datasheets

depending on who's  "supposing", I guess.

a better way to put it is that there is no assurance that they are comparable, though generally they are, especially for simple parameters.

thus it is wise to assume that they aren't not, especially for critical applications.